# Where is the geometry nodes modifier?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I couldn't find it anywhere in the dropdown, I also couldn't find it in "experimental" tab in user preference.

Comment: what is your version of Blender?

Comment: my version is 2.91

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for it in with other modifiers as subdivision and displace, i dont think you can find it there.
Select the object you want it to be applied and in the editor type (where you go to switch between 3d view and shader editor and all) you will find it there just in between shader and texture node editor options.
And its only available in 2.92 and above. I think . Not sure if 2.91 has it.

Comment: actually since 2.92 you can select it in the modifiers dropdown menu

Comment: @moonboots: Ha...i knew...you are a geometry nodes master too...! :D

Comment: no, I hate them  ;(((

Comment: @moonboots.. until they clean up the data flow a bit (there are plans) .. I have to agree with you. Atm, I think the workflow is horrible.

Comment: well, it seems powerful but it's a too mathematical approach for me, but I guess I will have to learn it, and at the end I'll probably find it more convenient than the current way

Comment: mine is 2.91. It doesnt have it?